# jquery blur validate one field at a time

Tags: jquery, validation

So I have the following fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/WF2J9/446/

Which checks if the field is empty, and adds the error class to the label for the field.

However it seems to check all the fields at once, how do I change the code so that when the user tabs/clicks out of say the name field, only the name label changes?

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" class="a">
    <label for="name">Name</label> : <input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" /> <br/>
    <label for="address">Address</label> : <input type="text" class="text" name="address" id="address" /> <br/>
    <label for="email">email</label> : <input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email" /> <br/>
</form>
```

JS

```
jQuery('input').on('blur', function() {
    jQuery('form input').each(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this);

        if($this.val() == '') {
            var $label = jQuery("label[for='"+this.id+"']")
            jQuery($label).addClass("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the loop inside the `blur` like:

```
jQuery('input').on('blur', function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    if ($this.val() == '') {
        var $label = jQuery("label[for='" + this.id + "']")
        $label.addClass("error");
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/palash/WF2J9/448/)

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple, couldnt work it out at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try `focusout` function:

Javascript:

```
 jQuery('input').focusout('blur', function () {

        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if ($this.val() == '') {
            var $label = jQuery("label[for='" + this.id + "']")
            jQuery($label).addClass("error");
        }
        else{
     var $label = jQuery("label[for='" + this.id + "']")
            jQuery($label).addClass("success");

    }


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Harpreet_devgun/WF2J9/449/